# Django Python not redirecting to login page after clicking sign up button

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

This is my first Django project and I am trying to get users to be redirected to a login page after they fill out a sign up form and click on the sign up button; however, instead my sign up form just reloads and I am still in my signup.html page. I am not sure why this is happening and any help would be greatly appreciated.(note -idk whether this will be relevant or not- that my html files are in a templates folder, .js and .css files are in a static folder, both separate and at the same level as my app folder)

(complete) signup.html:

```
{% load static%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" >
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>FitFlow - Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">
    <!--flatpickr-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
</head>
<body class="page-background">
    <div class = "container">
    <form class="form" action="{% url 'signup' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
      <h1 class="form_title">Create Account</h1>
      <div class="form_input_group">
        <input type="text" id= "name" class = "form_input" autofocus placeholder="Name" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form_input_group">
              <input type="text" id= "username" class = "form_input" placeholder="Username" required>
            </div>
      <div class="form_input_group">
        <input type="email" id="email" class = "form_input" autofocus placeholder="Email" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form_input_group">
        <input type="password" id="password1" class = "form_input" autofocus placeholder="Password" required>
        <div class="form_input-error-message"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form_input_group">
        <input type="password" id ="password2" class = "form_input" autofocus placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
        <div class="form_input-error-message"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form_input_group">
        <div class="custom_select">
          <select id="ageRange" name="ageRange" required>
            <option value="">Age Range</option>
            <option value="1">under 18</option>
            <option value="2">18-29</option>
            <option value="3">30-39</option>
            <option value="4">40-49</option>
            <option value="5">50+</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form_input_group">
        {% if error %}
        <div class="error-message">
          The passwords do not match.
        </div>
      {% endif %}
      </div>
      <div class="form_input_group">
        <input type="text" class="custom-lastPeriod" id="lastPeriod" name="lastPeriod" autofocus placeholder="First Day of Last Period" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form_input_group">
        <div class="custom_select">
          <select id="exercisePurpose" name="exercisePurpose" required>
            <option value="">Exercise Purpose</option>
            <option value="loseWeight">Lose Weight</option>
            <option value="buildMuscle">Build Muscle</option>
            <option value="improveEndurance">Improve Endurance</option>
            <option value="stayActive">Stay Active</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form_button_container">
        <button class ="form_button" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
      <p class="form_text">
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Already have an account? Log in</a>
      </p>

    </form>
  </div>

  <!--Bootsrap JS
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrate ></script>-->

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
  <script>
    flatpickr("#lastPeriod", {
      placeholder: "Select Last Period"
    });
  </script>
  <script src="{% static 'script2.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST["email"]
        password = request.POST["password1"]
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('mainpg')
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html', {"error": "Invalid username or password."})
    
    return render(request, 'login.html')

def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            username = request.POST['username']
        except MultiValueDictKeyError as e:
            messages.error(request, 'Please enter a username.')
            return redirect('signup')

        name = request.POST['name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        age_range = request.POST['ageRange']
        last_period = datetime.strptime(request.POST['lastPeriod'], "%Y-%m-%d")
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        exercise_purpose = request.POST['exercisePurpose']
        print("Sign up form submitted")
        if password1!= password2:
            return render(request, 'signup.html', {"error": "Passwords do not match."})
        
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, name=name, email=email, password=password1)
        user.save()
        
        print("Sign up form submitted")

        return redirect('/login')
    
    return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.app, name="app"),
    path('login/', views.login, name="login"),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name="signup"),
    path('mainpg/', views.mainpg, name="mainpg"),
    path('forgotp', views.forgotp, name="forgotp"),
]
```

settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..','collected_static')
```

Comment: The obvious explanation is that the passwords did not match.  Do you see "Sign up form submitted" in the console output?  Do you see it twice?  Does `signup.html` actually display the `{{ error }}` variable?

Comment: @JohnGordon this is what i get in my console: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 417
"GET /static/script.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1403
"GET /signup/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3298
"POST /signup/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
"GET /signup/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3298...im inputting the same password for both the 'password' and 'confirm password' input boxes, and in my signup.html code I've given 'password' the id=password1 and 'confirm password' the id=password2. thank you for the reply btw!

Comment: If you don't see "Sign up form submitted" in the console output, that means the code must be hitting the `except MultiValueDictKeyError` block.  And I'll ask again -- does the signup form have a place where it would actually display errors?  Can you show the whole template for signup.html?

Comment: `"POST /signup/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0` followed by `"GET /signup/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3298` means that the view is returning a redirect back to the signup.html form, and there's only one place that happens -- the `except` block, as I said above.  Is `username` actually an input item in the form?

Comment: @JohnGordon Oh okay i had added that block because I was getting an error whenever i inputted a username and tried to submit my form. Yes I wrote some code in for the error to be displayed, i'll edit my question to include the whole signup.html template. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id= "username" class = "form_input" placeholder="Username" required>
```

This is the problem.  This input element does not have a `name` attribute.  You're trying to use the `id` as though it were the `name`.

And the same with several other fields.

Also, there is nowhere on the form that displays `{{messages}}`, so that explains why the `messages.error()` call in the view was not displayed.